# sql join query when forgein key mapping available in third table

Tags: sql

I have three tables

1. user
2. role
3. user_role

   > user->{id,email,enabled,first_name} ([user sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw3aS.png))

   | id | email | enabled | first_name |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | sanchi@gmail.com | true | sachin |
   | 2 | altees@gmail.com | true | Altmas |
   | 3 | anna@gmail.com | true | Anna |

   > role ->{id,role_name} ([role sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOflk.png))

   | id | role_name |
   | --- | --- |
   | 1 | ADMIN |
   | 2 | TESTER |
   | 3 | CUSTOMER |

   > user_role->{user_id,role_id} ([user_role sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bfqb5.png))

   | user_id | role_id |
   | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 3 |
   | 2 | 1 |
   | 3 | 3 |
   | 3 | 3 |

I want a query which returns each user first_name   with role_name. I have created a nested query for this. but it is very complicated and not right way to do that. Has anyone a better enhanced query for the same? attached screenshot of all tables and expected results. ([Expected result sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12Sko.png))

```
sql
select m.first_name,z.role_name
from (select  u.first_name ,ur.role_id from "user" u inner join user_roles ur  on ur.user_id =u.id) m inner join roles z on m.role_id=z.id;
```

Expected results:

| first_name | role_name |
| --- | --- |
| saching | CUSTOMER |
| Altmas | ADMIN |
| Anna | TESTER |
| Anna | CUSTOMER |

---

Comment: Adding sample data and expected result would be helpful

Comment: And the query you have already tried is ...?

Comment: i have created the query for above problem but i think its more complicated anyone have alternate  enhanced query for this query -               select  m.first_name,z.role_name from (select  u.first_name ,ur.role_id from "user" u inner join user_roles ur  on ur.user_id =u.id) m inner join roles z on m.role_id=z.id;

Comment: Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68617486/edit) your original question and add all the required details: your current code, your concern about it, sample source data. Comments are not for significant details of the question

Comment: Also please choose a single DBMS you use. Do not spam tags. I've removed all inconsistent DBMS tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this

select
u.first_name,
r.role_name
from
user u,
roles r,
user_roles ur
where
u.id = ur.user_id
and r.id = ur.role_id;

Comment: You would really use commas in the `FROM` clause instead of proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  That is quite sad.

Comment: You can use `join`, the result will be exactly the same.